# Square Wave Voltage Level Shifting (Take 2)

Tags: mosfet, driver, level-shifting

After [my question before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/22303/5035), I tried to design a circuit with zener diodes and transistors for this issue.

It seems to work in simulation. Am I overdoing it? Are there any other simpler ways to do this, if so, could you please give any example or pseudo circuits?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Re "I couldn't understand how Q14 and Q15 works as an almost voltage follower" - I don't understand what you don't understand. You need to spell out what you need to know so I can answer it in one go. They are standard voltage followers so that can't be the problem. So?

Comment: @Russell McMahon re added see below answer's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - rushing - more later if needed. Try this for now.

This came from someone (on [PICLIST](http://www.piclist.com) perhaps?) on August 13th - MAY have been Olin.
 Can check later.

I use a different arrangement and will discuss later if needed.

This a more clever circuit than may appear, despite its apparent simplicity.
 It limits high side gate drive voltage without using a zener diode and it is faster than some alternatives because it does not saturate Q2.

Understand how it works!
  See description below.

[image]

Q2 inverts drive signal so FET gate goes low when input high,
 so input high = FET on with a PFET output.

CAREFULLY note the lack of input resistor to Q2.
 Understand why this is done and what it acheives.
 Q2 is an emitter follower and I_R14 ~= (Vin-Vbe)/R14.
 (~=3.3 - 0.6 = 2.7 mA in this case).

This generates a constant current in R14 when Vin is high.
 ie Q2 is NOT just an on/off switch as is often used in such cases.

The current in R14 also flows in R15.
 As R14 = 1k and R15 = 5K, the voltage across R15 is 5x as high as across R14.
 ie voltage across R15 = (Vin-Vbe) x R15/R14
 ~=  (3.3-0.6) x 5k/1k = 13.5V.
 So high side FET negative gate drive is limied without the use of a zener diode clamp.

ie when Q2 is on the bases of Q14 and Q15 will be driven below V+ (here = 30V) by about 13.5V so FET gate will be about 1 Vbe more +ve = about -13V below V+or here ~= +17V above ground.

The super magic here is that Q2 does NOT saturate so is fast switching compared to a saturated transistor.
 The person who drew this claimed 200 nS drive time which seems about correct.
 There are ways of making this faster but that's an excellent start.
 If you need an extra inversion you can add an extra PNP at the high side or an NPN at the low side.
 EITHER risks destroying the nice constant current drive system so think it through carefully.

More anon if needed.

---

**MOSFET gate zener:**

Having elimnated the need for a drive voltage limiting gate zener with the above circuit, I'm now going to suggest that one be added, but for a different reason

If the load is inductive, and in any case as a good precaution, it can be useful to have a zener diode between MOSFET gate and MOSFET source. This has a voltage rating somewhat higher than the maximum drive signal ever applied (so it never conducts in mormal use) but lower than VGS_absmax for the MOSFET.

Connect this "protection zener" near the MOSFET with shortest reasonably possible track lengths between MOSFET and zener.

BECAUSE:  In real world situations high energy noise can couple to MOSFET drain to MOSFET gate - one path is via MOSFET Vdg "Miller Capacitance" (look it up) and the other is from whatever source Murphy decides to use on any occasion. I have had MOSFETS which should [tm] have had no problems in theory actually dying within minutes in practice, but working reliably when a gate zener was added.

---

**FET GATE TRANSITION FROM OFF TO ON**

**Preparation - turning FET off to establish steady off state:**:

q14/q15 bases high so Q15 off.
 Q14 supplied base current by R15
 so FET gate pulled high by current through Q14
 until Gate comes to about 1Vbe below +
 so Q14 stops suppling current.

Everything stops happening,
 FET is off.
 Peace prevails.

**NOW**

Q2 on,
 FET drive is wanted!
 Q2 on,
 Q2C low = about 16.5V
 BUT FET gate is a ~= 1NF capacitor (inside FET)(which is why we need a hgh current driver)
 so Q15 base is at 16.5V
 but FET gate is at 29.4V
 so there is about 12V+ across R31!
 so Q15 TRIES to supply about 12/10 = 1.2A into FET gate.
 FET gate voltage drops from 29.4v as I comes from Q15.

When FET gate reaches about 17V
 Q15 has no current source and effectively floats.
 ie in steady states there is no current and no current paths for either Q14 or Q15 - they only get sensible currents when the FET gate cap is charging or discharging which is why the circuit makes little sense when in steady state.

Comment: I couldn't understand how Q14 and Q15 works as an almost voltage follower

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. You need to spell out what you need to know so I can answer it in one go. They are standard voltage followers so that can't be the problem. So?

Comment: I don't understand the working principle of Q14 and Q15. It is a push-pull output stage, but I am puzzled in the working of it. Cannot understand how Q15 turns on when Q14 is off. How does the current flow from the emitter of Q15 to the base of Q15 where there is no current coming from the emitter of Q14?

Comment: I checked the datasheet of BC817, however there are max 100nA current flowing "from emitter to base" and "from collector to base". No info on collector to emitter. Is Q15 turned on with the help of Q14's collector to emitter cutoff leakage current?

Comment: Remove Q14, cycle circuit. Work out what Q15 does. Then replace Q14, remove Q15, cycle circuit, work out what Q14 does. Both are independent. When Q2 is off Q14 drives the FET gate, When Q2 is on Q15 drives the FET gate. Q14 and Q15 are "emitter followers" . Look up "emitter follower" and understand what they do and how they work. They have a voltage gain of just less than 1 and a current gain of "high". Their job is to provide large current to charge and discharge the FET gate capacitance when required. Please be sure to understand emitter followers before asking any related questions.

Comment: I understand the emitter followers now, my previous comment about them being voltage followers was silly. I understand how Q14 is on when Q2 is off. However I don't understand how Q15 is turned on when Q14 is off: Where does Q15 supply its emitter to base current and voltage from when Q14 is off?

Comment: @abdullahkahraman - see addition to answer.

Comment: Does this mean that push-pull output stage cannot drive a purely resistive load because there is no current source for Q15, as it sinks current from load?

Comment: @abdullahkahraman - No. It will (try to) drive anything you connect it to. As long as Q15's emitter is being pulled to or driven by a signal more than 1 Vbe above Q15's base then Q15 will turn on and sink current into ground to "try" and pull the load down to within a Vbe of it's base. Similarly, if Q14's emitter is pulled to more than 1 Vbe below Q14's base then Q14 will turn on and source current from V+ to try and pull the load up to within 1 Vbe of Q14's base. Peace reigns when Vout is within a 2Vbe range around the commoned base voltage as then both transistors meet the above aims.

Comment: After looking at the circuit in the answer after almost a year, I see that the circuit cannot be from Olin, look at how the schematic is driven. lol

Comment: @abdullahkahraman - :-). I'm not sure of you exact point, but if you mean the lack of resistor then that is exactly the point of this circuit. No series input resistor is used because   Q2 drives R14 as an emitter follower (so no input R) BUT then mirrors the voltage across R14 into R15, multiplied by the ratio of their relative resistances. Which is what the circuit is "about". | If that's not the point of the comment, please explain - mustn't miss a subtle joke :-)

Comment: I see that the lack of the base resistor is *needed*. What I meant was how the schematic is *drawn*. Yeah, sorry for my bad English skills :) The schematic is so ugly :) Btw, thanks again for this circuit, it is so clever and was very helpful.

Comment: Ah. Yes. You are absolutely correct. Definitely not drawn up by Olin on any day when he was any of awake, sane or sober.